# If a worker earns \$300 for each day he works and loses \$60 for each day he is absent, given his income, how many days did he work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> A worker's wage is Rs. $300$ for each day he works and he is fined Rs. $60$ for everyday when he is absent. If he gets Rs
>    $7560$ at the end of a month, how many days did he work?

My Attempt:

Let he worked for $x$ days and he was absent for $y$ days.
Then,

Total earning=$300x$
Total Fine=$60y$
Now,

$$300x=7650$$
$$x=25.2$$

However, the answer in my book is 26days. Please correct, where is my mistake?

Comment: You didn't take into account the fine for the $y$ days he was absent. EDIT: Also, you need to take into account the length of the month, which is a little confusing, since it can go from $28$ to $31$.

Comment: $300 x - 60 y = 7560$

Comment: I'd say $7560$ is more like $300x-60y$ where $x+y=30$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the number of days he was absent in terms of $x$ to make it easier.

Present for $x$ days, so he was paid $300x$.

Absent for $30-x$ days so he lost $(60)(30-x)$.

The total paid is $7560$, so the equation is $300x-(60)(30-x)=7560$. Note the minus before the amount of money he lost!

Solving, $x=26$.

Comment: How can you assume a $30$ day month before doing the calculations?

Comment: @Henry Sorry? I'm sure it's a 30 day month... the question probably wouldn't be trying to trick the answerer

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be a Diophantine equation.  We have $300x-60y = 7560$. Divide by $60$ to get $5x-y=126$.  By the usual Euclidean Algorithm method (or by inspection), we find the solution to be $x=t, y = -126 +5t$, where $t$ is an integer.  Now we select a solution that makes sense.  First $y$ should be at least $0$, so $t\geq 26$.  Second, it's a month, so $x+y$ shouldn't be greater than $31$.  That is $t+(-126+5t) = 6t-125 \leq 31$ or $6t\leq 156$ or $t\leq 26$.
That leaves $t=26$.